# Hide Path until animation starts Android

Tags: android, animation, path, target

So I am animating the letter "E" being drawn, each one of the targets in the code below is a different stroke which come one after the other using the timeOffset, my question is how can I hide each path until it starts being animated? So for example "path" would animate first and path2, path3 and path4 are all hidden until their animations start.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:drawable="@drawable/cap_e">

<target
    android:name="bezier2"
    android:animation="@animator/path"
    android:startOffset="500" />
<target
    android:name="bezier3"
    android:animation="@animator/path2" />
<target
    android:name="bezier4"
    android:animation="@animator/path3" />
<target
    android:name="bezier5"
    android:animation="@animator/path4" />
</animated-vector>
```

Answer (score -1):

on shapeshifter, delete the path data to blank.